# Why can Vue render function process single file component?

Tags: vue.js, render, vue-cli

I use Vue cli and implement `simple-webpack` template.

In the entry file `main.js`, there's a code like below:

```
render: h => h(App)
```

I know that `h` is an alias of `createElement` function, I wonder why a single file component like `App` can be passed in as an argument, official vue document didn't mention this.

Does anyone know why is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single file component (SFC) in vue js has a `.vue` extension.

In webpack we use a loader called [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/) which  tests for `.vue` files

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
      }
      // other vue-loader options go here
    }
}
```

these SFCs are converted into a plain  [es6 modules](https://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwib643NrIzaAhVDto8KHSavDrwQFggXMAQ&usg=AOvVaw0OK0U07lJJou7fNt-LEp94) .

The `<template>` part is transformed into render functions by [`vue-template-complier`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler) and injected into the exported module.

The `<style>` tag is similarly processed by any preprocessors for sass or less and then by  `Post-css` to scope the CSS accordingly and dynamically added inside the the `<head>` as `<style>` tag with the help of [`vue-style-loader`.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader)

For example if the **App.vue** file looks as follows:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="myClass">{{msg}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                msg: "Vue is awesome!"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It is converted to a plain module where exported as an object shown below:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            msg: "Vue is awesome!"
        }
    },
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement("div", 
            [createElement("p", {class: {'myClass': true}}), this.msg]
        )
    }
}
```

This is imported as `import App from './path/to/App.vue` and used in root vue instance as

```
 new Vue({
     el:"#app",
     render: h => h(App)
 })
```

You can check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wqe40wm/3/) where `App` is passed as a plain object to `render` function of root vue instance.

For more detailed info you can checkout this [video](https://youtu.be/wZN_FtZRYC8) where Evan You explains it more elaborately.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks bro, you are super pro!

Comment: @ArelLin :-)...there are many good ones even better than me....we are all here to learn... I learnt a lot from **bert** - [https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert] and **acdcjunior** - [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior] who stay active on vue.js tag